# Modal form made in Bootstrap with JavaScript and PHP not sending email on submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I've built this page using a button to trigger a modal that has a contact form.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#stayInformed">Stay Informed</button>
```

I'm trying to submit that form to the php at the top of the page to send myself an email.  However, the php is not sending the email nor is it displaying the echos.

```
<?php
$myemail = 'user@email.com';
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$company = strip_tags($_POST['company']);

echo "<span class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been received. Thanks! Here is what you submitted:</span><br><br>";
echo "<stong>Name:</strong> ".$name."<br>"; 
echo "<stong>Email:</strong> ".$email."<br>";   
echo "<stong>Company:</strong> ".$company."<br>";


$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
"Email: $email\n Company \n $company";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}?>
```

There is JavaScript at the bottom which should trigger the form POST.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('form#contact').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php", 
            data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                $("#stayInformed").modal('hide');
                alert(document.getElementById("name").value + " " + document.getElementById("email").value + " " + document.getElementById("company").value);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }   
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

The button is triggering the modal correctly and the JavaScript seems to be functioning correctly.  It closes the modal on submit and if I change the php pointer to something that doesn't exist it throws the error.

Entire page with modal posted below:

```
<?php
$myemail = 'user@email.com';
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
$name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
$email = strip_tags($_POST['email']);
$company = strip_tags($_POST['company']);

echo "<span class=\"alert alert-success\" >Your message has been received. Thanks! Here is what you submitted:</span><br><br>";
echo "<stong>Name:</strong> ".$name."<br>"; 
echo "<stong>Email:</strong> ".$email."<br>";   
echo "<stong>Company:</strong> ".$company."<br>";


$to = $myemail;
$email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message. ".
" Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".
"Email: $email\n Company \n $company";
$headers = "From: $myemail\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email";
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
}?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->

    <title>Modal Form Test</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <p><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#stayInformed">Stay Informed</button>
          </p>
 </div> <!-- /container -->          
</div> <!-- /jumbotron -->

<!-- stayInformed Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="stayInformed" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="stayInformed">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Stay Informed!</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <form class="form-horizontal" id="contact" role="form" method="post" action="index.php">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Register Below</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="First Last"></input> 
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
      <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@company.com"> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Company</label>
      <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Company"></input> 
      </div>
      </div>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="contact"></input>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- JavaScript for modal form -->

<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('form#contact').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php", 
            data: $('form.contact').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                $("#stayInformed").modal('hide');
                alert(document.getElementById("name").value + " " + document.getElementById("email").value + " " + document.getElementById("company").value);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("failure");
            }   
        });
    });
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**:  I changed javascript a bit ad the value of some ids to get rid of repeats.  Still not working.  I can now see the values in my success alert but it still doesn't appear that the PHP is executing.

**Edit 2**:  After some troubleshooting it appears that there are no variables being sent to the php in $_POST.  I'm not sure why...

Comment: The  `<input type="submit" ...` will submit the page,thereby preventing the AJAX call.

Comment: How should I be doing it?

Comment: Try replacing `<input type="submit" ...` with `<input type="button" ...` and try once.

Comment: I tried using `<input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="stayInformed"></input>` but it's still not sending the email or showing the echoes.

Comment: Or adding e.preventDefault();

Comment: Try adding die(var_dump($_POST)) to your PHP script right after <?php. Then when the javascript fires, look at the resulting file using your browser's Development Console (r-click -> Inspect Element). That will show you if your PHP script is at least getting the right values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the JavaScript to code to:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#contact').submit(function(event) {
        var formData = {
            'name'              : $('input[id=name]').val(),
            'email'             : $('input[id=email]').val(),
            'company'           : $('input[id=company]').val()
        };
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "index.php", 
            data: formData,
            success: function(msg){
                $("#stayInformed").modal('hide');
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("form post failed");
            }   
        });
    });
 });
</script>
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this:

```
$("input#submit").click(function(){
   // stuff
});
```

By this:

```
$('form#stayInformed').on('submit', function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     // stuff
});
```

Resume:
Not listening click on button, you must to listen the form submit event. the preventDefault() method disables default action, that is submit the form without ajax. With this code, all runs ok.

Next time, please, try it yourself and search how it mades in google. This is basic javascript premises.

Good luck

## EDIT

Note that the ID #stayInformed is duplicated in a DIV and in the FORM. It's very bad practice. Please, be sure that the IDs aren't duplicated in the html code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm sorry this is so basic.  Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be working for me.  I did take your advice and changed the form to `id="stayInformedForm"`  It still seems that the JavaScript is executing correctly but the php is not at all.